# how to get only value from formula cell in csv file using pandas dataframe or any other python library?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have one csv file which having four columns. Last 3 columns having excel function formulas. Now how to get only value from formula cell in csv file using pandas dataframe or any other python library? 
For example 
Score column having formula like =Sum(A1+B1)

Comment: Your question is no clear. CSV format dose not support formula. Basically it is plain text.

Comment: I created csv file with formula using below code

Comment: import pandas as  pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
Rowcnt = 2
df1.set_value(Rowcnt, 'Mark1','50')
df1.set_value(Rowcnt, 'Mark2','50')
df1.set_value(Rowcnt, 'SCORE', '=SUM(A2:B2)')
df1.to_csv('E:\test.csv', index=False, header=True)

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you correctly you want to view the value of the sum of mark1 and mark 2 not the formula. You can use pd.DataFrame.sum, see this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mark1': [50,60,70], 'Mark2': [60,70,50]})
df['SCORE'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: I know this concept but some columns are dependent on the other columns for example ColumnA

Comment: I know this concept but some columns are dependent on the other columns that having dependenies for example Score column need to update with calculation all 500 rows then only I can compute the other column for example Other column function like "max" to find maximum number df1['High score'].iloc[:MaxRow].max() . Here Maxrow is variable which will hold some row count. Like this lot columns are depended on other column so I have to use for loop multiple times to compute each column